# Adding Numpy Arrays across dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with identical keys, where the values of each dictionary are NumPy arrays of the same size.

Here's the example

```
a = {"a": np.array([1,2]),"b": np.array([2,4]),}
b = {"a": np.array([5,7]),"b": np.array([12,34]),}
c = [a,b]
```

I would like to sum the values(Numpy arrays) for the same keys across all of the dictionaries.

I have tried Counter form collections but it only seems to work for scalar values. I tried to do it with two loops but got confused. I probably can do it with three loops but is there another more elegant way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `sum()` and `dict`-comprehension:

```
keys = a.keys()
{k: sum(x[k] for x in c) for k in keys}
```

This assumes that the keys in `a` are found in all `dict`s, otherwise you would need to check for key existence (e.g. `sum(x[k] for x in c if k in x)`).

The full example reads:

```
import numpy as np


a = {"a": np.array([1,2]),"b": np.array([2,4]),}
b = {"a": np.array([5,7]),"b": np.array([12,34]),}
c = [a,b]


keys = a.keys()
{k: sum(x[k] for x in c) for k in keys}
# {'a': array([6, 9]), 'b': array([14, 38])}
```

Comment: nice and elegant

Comment: keep in mind that `reduce()` may be faster as one of the loops is in C.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
{k:a[k]+b[k] for k in a.keys()}
```

Or in general with `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(lambda x,y: {k:x[k]+y[k] for k in x.keys()}, c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': array([6, 9]), 'b': array([14, 38])}
```

Comment: Yes, the reduce formula worked. It seems slightly unclear to me how it works, but I guess I will check it out. Thanks.